# Change users while logged to ssh server with nautilus

Tags: 16.04, ssh, nautilus

When I try to connect directly to server with ssh over terminal, I cannot connect directly as a root. First I need to login with LDAP credentials, and then I am able to switch as root.

When I am connecting over Ubuntu's Nautilus over ssh, first I connect with LDAP credentials. How to obtain root access while already logged as another account in Nautilus?

Answer (score 0):

Launch nautilus with root access with `gksu nautilus`. In terminal, you can elevate your access to root using `sudo su` and it will prompt you for the root password.

Comment: you tried this??? I cannot even connect  to server over ssh when I am running as root.
http://i.imgur.com/KGsMd7t.jpg
This is mint's nemo, but its not working with Nautilus either

Comment: I want to change to root while I am connected over ssh/sftp with regular (non-root) user